# Ratio of sides of tangent triangles

Tags: trigonometry

From an external point E a tangent is drawn to a circle at  T and also a central/diametrical secant (passing through  centre O) cutting the circle along diameter NF. Show, by an as much possible elegant proof  that:

$$ \frac{EF}{ET}= \tan TNF, \quad \frac{EN}{ET}= \cot TNF. $$

EDIT1:

Answering own question ( although not any fun, could not figure it out at time of posting).

Construction:  Join FT and produce backwards to cut y-axis at Q. Angle chasing shows $ ET=EQ, $ triangle $ETQ$  is isosceles.   $ ENTQ$ is a cyclic quadrilateral, triangles $NTF,QEF $ are similar, result follows.

[image: Tgt Triangles]

Comment: Similarity of triangles ETN EFT lead to circle property ET^2 = EF. EN ; but how the ratio is $\tan TNO$ is not immediately obvious ( to me).

Comment: I am sorry but the first equality does not look verified. In fact, we could reverse the definition by saying that we can take a point $T$ on the circle, and $E$ is any point on the tangent to the circle at point $T$. The problem is that, as $E$ varies on this tangent, $EF/ET$ varies; whereas $\tan TNF$ is constant...

Comment: The variable central secant EOF cuts the circle at variable points N,F  making angle TNO = TNF is quite variable in  (black,red) configurations,

Comment: With your figure, I see that take the "secant" passing through E **but you don't say it in your question !**

Comment: Repetition about E was not needed, in any case  after the above explanative comment. Anyhow shall edit the question.

Comment: I vote for reopening.